# WebStorm cannot resolve Firebase 9 imports

Tags: firebase, phpstorm, webstorm

My problem is that my IDE (WebStorm) doesn't recognize Firebase imports. It throws the following error:

> Cannot resolve symbol getFirestore.

Here are my imports:

```js
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import {
    getAuth,
    setPersistence,
    browserSessionPersistence,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
```

The code works absolutely fine, but I'd love to have the autocompletion and a file without any errors.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find a solution? I tried updating webstorm to latest version, but didn't work...

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, you need to mark node_modules/@firebase in Webstorm to be included... Might be "Mark as not excluded"

Comment: yes, this is indeed a solution: when installing `firebase`, the `@firebase` module all the stuff is re-exported from is not listed as a dependency/devDependency in a `package.json` and thus is not indexed by default, so you need un-excluding it manually