# Imports not working on Firebase Client v9 (npm)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, npm, webstorm

**Context:**

I finally got the initiative do adapt the Firebase library in my app from 9.0.2 compat to the new modular, tree-shakable library. I'm on Windows 10, using WebStorm, and my package.json only has the dependency `{ "firebase": "^9.0.2" }`.

**What should work:**

When I try to import `initializeApp` as shown in the documentation:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
const firebaseApp = initializeApp({ /* config */ });
```

I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'initializeApp'`.

**Attempts to fix:**

I am testing this new Firebase library in a simple Vue.js project, only configured with ESLint and Babel. I tried deleting the `node_modules` folder, cleaning the chace, reinstalling everything from npm, but nothing seems to make the standard import work.

**Current workaround:**

I looked into `node_modules/firebase` and, sure enough, all the standard functions are there, inside javascript files such as `firebase-app.js` and `firebase-auth.js`. This means that I can import everything as follows:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/firebase-app';
const firebaseApp = initializeApp({ /* config */ });
```

But I'm sure this is not normal nor expected, as I seem to be the only one that had reported this behavior. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:** As @Dharmaraj said, this error does not happen when the same project is configured in VS Code, so this seems to be a WebStorm issue.

Comment: Are you using Webstorm by chance?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, I am!

Comment: Have you tried opening same project in VS Code? I don't get this warning there, Webstorm shows me this warning when using JS project only. Works fine in TS.

Comment: I just tried it on a blank VS Code project and it works, indeed. Thanks, @Dharmaraj! I will add the WebStorm tag on my question.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69242763/783119 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52739#focus=Comments-27-5202170.0-0 / https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52727#focus=Comments-27-5199952.0-0

Comment: Yes! This is it, works like a charm. I will create an answer for anyone with the same problem in WebStorm. Thank you very much, @LazyOne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it really was a WebStorm problem. As @LazyOne identified, we can find the solution for related `Cannot resolve symbol ...` issues [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52739#focus=Comments-27-5202170.0-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233662/webstorm-cannot-resolve-firebase-9-imports/69242763), regarding both WebStorm and PhpStorm.

**TL;DR:** All you have to do is: open `node_modules`, right-click on the module (folder) `@firebase` and select `Mark as not excluded`.

It means that your IDE will now index those files, and importing functions from files inside `@firebase` is now possible, since they are recognized by the program.

Thank you to everyone involved!